# Jquery mobile - slider - doesn't render correctly

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a strange problem with slider. It does not render correctly. See the picture: [image]

as you can see, I don't have "slider" in my slider :). Just a up/down arrows.

This is my cod:

```
<head>
...
    <!-- General Style -->
<link href='css/style.css' id='styles-css' media='all' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">


<!-- Scripts -->
<script src='js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js'></script>
<script src='js/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js'></script>
<script src='js/bootstrap.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script src='js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js'></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
...
 </head>
```

and simple slider from jqm page

```
<label for="slider-1">Input slider:</label>
<input type="range" name="slider-1" id="slider-1" value="60" min="0" max="100">
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Are you intentionally mixing jQM, bootstrap, and jQueryUI?

Comment: I removed UI and bootstrap and it's working. thanks.